# Pytest ERROR: -o/--override-ini expects option=value style (got: 'utputFormat')

Tags: pytest

I'm trying to run Pytest on a single file on Windwos like so:

```
python -m pytest C:\auto\tests\shared\test_shared.py
```

This results in the following error:

```
ERROR: -o/--override-ini expects option=value style (got: 'utputFormat')
```

Needless to say, I do not have any pytest.ini files or overriding it in anyway. My test file simply sleeps and exits.

This happens on Windows only, but not on Mac.

Comment: Somewhere you get `-outputFormat` in the command line, but without more information, this is impossible to understand. The full output from `pytest` might help, any configuration files that may be found (conftest.py, pyproject.toml, pytest.ini), the list of installed plugins as reported by pytest. You might also just grep for "outputFormat" in the path and check if you get any hits (there is no such option in pytest itself).